# EF Codefirst update many to many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I need some help on adding roles to user in a many-many situation.

So I have `User` with many `Role` and `Role` has many `User`.

I figured my current `Update()` method in my repository wont work. How can I build a repository method that allows me to remove all previous roles and add new roles to user?

This is what I currently have:

```
    public User UpdateUser(User user, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<User, object>>> properties)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserId))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("user does not exist");
        }
        else
        {
            db.Users.Attach(user);
            foreach (var selector in properties)
            {
                string propertyName = Helpers.PropertyToString(selector.Body);
                db.Entry(user).Property(propertyName).IsModified = true;
            }

        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        return user;
    }
```

Is this the right way to update a user? I'm assuming everything the detached. This is how I'm calling this to add roles to user:

```
        User user = new User();
        user.UserId = userId;
        user.Roles = new Domain.Role{ RoleId = 1}; //Assuming there is a role with ID = 1
        userRepo.UpdateUser(user, new List<Expression<Func<User, object>>>
                                      {
                                          u => u.Roles
                                      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working in a detached scenario you might want to look into the object state manager. See these two answers for more info.

[Entity Framework Code First - Add Child Entity to Parent by Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264720/entity-framework-code-first-add-child-entity-to-parent-by-primary-key/5266719#5266719)

[Save a relation with between two entities an N-N association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025823/save-a-relation-with-between-two-entities-an-n-n-association/5025954#5025954)

The first one is a simple example where a single child is added without roundtriping the db. The second one is more complex but I still haven't found a good way to clear the relationship without telling it which childs to delete.

There is a possibility I haven't looked at yet and it is to use the RelationshipManager which you can get from the ObjectStateManager. It contains a few methods to get releated collections so maybe you could use that somehow.